# onListItemClick is not getting invoked in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and custom layout consisting of TextView, ImageView, ImageButton. I want my image button to behave like RadioButton. But my onListItemClick event is not getting invoked.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> text;
    ArrayList<String> Count;

    int count;

    public MyListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> Count) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.textAnswers = text;
        this.optionCount = Count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Count.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        }

        ImageButton choice = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
        if(imageChoice != null) {
            choice.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_unselected);

        }

        TextView txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView);
        txt.setText(Count.get(position));

        TextView txtText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewAnswer);
        txtText.setText(textAnswers.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And my onListItemClick as,

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, v, position, id);
    ImageButton choice = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
    choice.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_selected); 
}
```

Now plz any one help to give my imagebutton the behavior like radiobutton. Most important i missed is that my onListItemClick is not getting invoked.
Also I have set the android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:clickable="false" of all controls on my custom_layout.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you call `setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: @MByD no i didnt called setOnItemClickListener.. Do I have to?

Comment: Yes, you need to set it as the listener, otherwise, how will it be called?

Comment: My Activity extends ListActivity. So I think my onListItemClick should work for this? And also, my list is of android:id="@id/android:list". plz can you post some sample from which I will get an clear view.

Comment: please post your activity code, the listadapter is less interesting.

Comment: In onCreate I am doing, MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, text, Count);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: In the `layout.xml`, do you have [`clickable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable) set to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a setOnItemClickListener to your ListView in the main activity, if you do not, you'll never get a call to the itemClick.

for instance:

OnCreate() Method:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

// Create the method below and let the activity implement onitemclicklistener

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
//set action here
 }
```

that should work :)

Answer (score 2):

If your activity is a ListActivity and your list view has the id = @android:id/list than your onListItemClick will be called without you having to set the listener.

Comment: Yes right, coz I have one more list on another activity with simple adapter here my onListItemClick get called. But why its not getting called for list with BaseAdapter?

Comment: If remove the image button from my custom layout the onListItemClick is getting invoked. Now what i am missing for imagebutton?

Answer (score 1):

You might need `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` set in your list item view. That solved it for me.

```
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these values ​​in the XML for the ImageButton, then it should work.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```